# Insert row wise different images in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I am working on SSRS in witch i have data set with `[First, Last, Email and Image]`
image contains name of image and when ever i use this image i have to put `www.something.com/images/` at start of this field

Now I am using this in SSRS something like this

Is it possible that what i am doing if yes some one kindly help

[image]

I am using following expression in first column

```
="www.something.com/images/"+Fields!Image_Path.Value
```

FYP: I am using SQL server 2012 and Visual Studio 2013

What I am trying to ask: I have image name in database and i want to insert that image in report something like here is my name Taimur and i want to insert image of taimur in first field the problem is, i have only image name in database and when ever i have to use that image i have to put `www.something.com/images` before image name because i have physically existed images on that path
Hopefully you understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http:// and join your strings using & not +

Comment: Thanks... Its using, i think `VBScript` or `VBA` and in that language & is used for string concatination

Comment: Yes, it's VBScript-ish